# Tool tip registeration

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, registration

What is the meaning of this sentence.

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(jTree);
```

Can we register super component also by using given statement so that we don't need to register all the individual component which is inheriting registered super class.

Comment: no, there is no support to register complete hierarchies. But on the bright side: most components register themselves when calling setTooltipText with a not-null value.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your reply.Can we do the same for jTree also because i didn't find anything like that for jTree.

Comment: tree registers itself automatically (always), the (per-node) tooltip has to be set on the renderer. On the how-to: it's the same as for a JTable, the tutorial might have an example (didn't check, though)

Comment: Can you please help me by replying with specific link so that it will be help full for other users also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I was wrong when stating that a JTree registers itself with the manager always (as does JTable): you have to do it manually *and* implement a custom renderer providing the per-node tooltip:

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
// need to register manually 
// (that is does _not_ automatically as f.i. JTable
// either register the tree
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(tree);
// or set a not-null tooltip text to the tree
// tree.setToolTipText("default if node has none or outside node");
TreeCellRenderer r = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
            Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf,
            int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf,
                row, hasFocus);
        setToolTipText("I'm a leaf: " + leaf);
        return this;
    }

};
tree.setCellRenderer(r);
```

Comment: hmmm works for me correctly only for 2nd and next elements, never for 1st node or leaf or whatever (Win8, Java6/7), for 1st only if isSelected

Comment: not, or yes works only in the case that you'll going with mouse outside of Rectangle occupated by JTree, not, wrong, brrrrrr :-)

Comment: @mKorbel and the meaning is ...?